# Is there a way of causing a compile error if trying to assign a negative number to an unsigned container?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

Is there a way of guarding against the resulting binary from the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2711522/594137)?  Ideally by way of an error at compile time. Example code from the question:

```
unsigned int nVal = 0;
nVal = -5;  // no error!
```

Comment: `compiler error` at runtime? *Assignment* happens at runtime.

Comment: There might be a way by exploiting convoluted conversion rules, but it would mean changing your code so it doesn't use `unsigned int` anymore, but something like `EnforcedUnsignedInt` with other intermediate classes to cause different code generation when using `operator =` with signed / unsigned. Verdict: Not practical / realistic.

Comment: The initial assignment of `0` (which is signed), rather than `0u`, would presumably also generate the warning/error you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using g++, the switch `-Wsign-conversion` will warn about the conversion, and `-Werror` will make that warning an error.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was after!

Comment: In Visual Studio, you can also turn on a "treat warnings as errors" feature on a project build options. And the compiler should raise a warning for possible loss of data when converting from int to unsigned int.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: Apart from @thiton's answer.

With the simple assignment it's not possible. However, if you assign the value in a little *special wrapped way*, then it can help. i.e.

```
nVal = -5;
```

should be replaced with,

```
Assign<-5>(nVal);
```

Where, `Assign()` looks like,

```
template<int VAL>
void Assign (unsigned int &nVal)
{
  typedef int arr[(VAL >= 0) 1 : -1];
  nVal = VAL;
}
```

[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/uFBTB).