# Weird integer overflow logic

Tags: c++, integer-arithmetic

For the following code I get an overflow but sadly I cannot seem to understand why.

```
std::int8_t smallValue         = -1;
unsigned int value             = 500;
std::uint8_t anotherSmallValue = 1;

auto test = smallValue * value * anotherSmallValue;
```

Afterwards `test` is a quite large value.

Could someone explain, what happens here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens if I assign a negative value to an unsigned variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711522/what-happens-if-i-assign-a-negative-value-to-an-unsigned-variable)

Comment: For me the lesson here is to **always** set `-Werror=sign-conversion`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the compiler sees `smallValue * value`, it must decide what the data type of the result is going to be, given the input data types `signed` (8 bits) and `unsigned int` (usually, either 16 or 32 bits).  The rules of C++ state that in this situation, the result will be unsigned.  Therefore, the value of `smallValue * value` cannot be `-500`, as you are expecting; instead, the value `-500` is interpreted as a POSITIVE number.

Furthermore, you are here multiplying an 8-bit value by a value that is typically either 16- or 32-bit.  The rules of C++ in this scenario state that the smaller-storage value will first be cast to the same size as the larger; so in this case the result of `smallValue * value` will indeed be large enough to store a number of magnitude `500`.

Proceeding to multiply by the unsigned quantity `anotherSmallValue` (=1) results in another `unsigned` with the same value.

Because you are using `auto`, the return type is therefore deduced to be `unsigned`.

Simply by casting back to a `signed` (by, for example, defining the value `test` as an `int`, rather than an `auto`, will in turn typically cast the result of the entire operation back to a `signed` value, without changing the bits internally; this will then properly display `-500`, as you expect; however, as other posters have noted, this is rather dangerous in theory because it's not techincally guaranteed to work, although it usually will work this way with today's compilers.

Answer (score 6):

result type will be `unsigned int` [test here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1uymEV%241). `smallValue * value` `smallValue` will be casted to unsigned, so this expression is `(unsigned)-1 * 500`. However, if you compile this code with `-Wsign-conversion` - compiler tells you, that you do bad things. [link](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1uymEV%243)

Comment: +1 for mentioning `-Wsign-conversion`. I read the _gcc_ docs for it and was shocked that it isn't enabled for `-Wconversion`.

Answer (score 2):

You will get the same result with just the first two variables (`smallValue * value`).

First, integral promotions are applied to both values: `int8_t` becomes `int`, and `unsigned int` remains as it is.

Then this rule from C++11 5/9 is applied to determine the result type:

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than or equal to the
>   rank of the type of the other operand, **the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to
>   the type of the operand with unsigned integer type**.

So `-1` must be converted to `unsigned int` using modular arithmetic, giving a large positive number. Multiplying by 500 will overflow (again using modular arithmetic), giving a different large number.

Answer (score 1):

Make 'auto' into a signed type and you will be fine:

```
long test = smallValue * value * anotherSmallValue;
```

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "fine". That will give the same (large positive) result if `long` is larger than `unsigned int`. If it's the same size, or you change it to `int`, then technically you'll get undefined behaviour due to signed overflow; but in practice you'll get the "expected" result of -500 on most modern computers.

Answer (score 1):

Operating with mixed types is always prone to such errors. I advise you to use a single type for arithmetic operations