# Why c++ string1.size() minus string2.size() got wrong answer?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string haystack = "aaa";
  string needle = "aaaa";
  int i = 0;
  if(i <= haystack.size() - needle.size())
    cout<<"why 0<-1?"<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:
why 0<-1?
Press any key continue...

Why we got this output? I think "if" statement should not be executed cause 0 is greater than 3-4=-1.
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `string::size`'s return type.

Comment: @ZDF thanks! I know I've made a mistake..

Comment: Why not directly compare the two values you want to compare? `if (haystack.size() < needle.size())`  Also, why use the variable `i` in the comparison?

Comment: You should turn on compiler warnings to let the compiler tell you about such things.

Comment: @e0k thanks. I use s.size() to implement my strStr(). See Leetcode Q28.

Answer (score 10):

The return type of [`std::string::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) is [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).

This is an *unsigned* type. Therefore since your subtraction results in a negative value, [it will wrap around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711522/what-happens-if-i-assign-a-negative-value-to-an-unsigned-variable) based on [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), resulting in a very large number far greater than `0`.

Comment: Thanks. Than -1 turns into an unsigned 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: Beware, on a 64-bit processor, it will probably turn into 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Answer (score 2):

For historical reasons the standard library generally uses [`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t), which is an *unsigned* type, as the result type of size functions. One exception is [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count). But `std::string::size()` is among the `size_t` functions,

Since the language guarantees modular arithmetic for unsigned type expressions, you get wrap-around where `-1` becomes the largest value of the unsigned type.

---

Another and IMO more obviously silly consequence is that

```
std::string( "Hello" ).size() < -1
```

is *guaranteed*. Just pure nonsense as source code text, when one recalls that the purpose of high level source code is to communicate more clearly to humans.

---

To avoid this mess you can define a logical signed `Size` type as an alias for `ptrdiff_t` (which is the signed type counterpart to `size_t`) and ditto size functions `static_size`, `n_items` and `length`, plus a checker `is_empty`, as follows:

*sizes_and_lengths.hpp*

```
#pragma once
// p/cppx/core_language_support/sizes_and_lengths.hpp
// Copyright © Alf P. Steinbach 2015. Boost Software License 1.0.

#include <p/cppx/core_language_support/basic_types.hpp>
#include <p/cppx/core_language_support/overloading.hpp>             // cppx::(Object_argument etc.)
#include <p/cppx/core_language_support/type_builders.hpp>           // cppx::(Ptr_, Ref_, Array_of_, ...)
#include <p/cppx/core_language_support/tmp/If_.hpp>                 // cppx::(If_, Is_)
#include <p/cppx/core_language_support/tmp/type_relationships.hpp>  // cppx::Is_convertible_to_

#include <string>           // std::basic_string
#include <utility>          // std::declval

namespace progrock{ namespace cppx{
    // These templates use size_t to accommodate g++, which has bug in this area.

    // static_size()
    // Static capacity of a collection.

    template< class Type, size_t n >
    constexpr
    auto static_size( In_ref_<Raw_array_of_<n, Type>> )
        -> Size
    { return n; }

    template< class Type, size_t n >
    constexpr
    auto static_size( In_ref_<Array_of_<n, Type>> )
        -> Size
    { return n; }

    template< size_t n >
    constexpr
    auto static_size( In_ref_<std::bitset<n>> )
        -> Size
    { return n; }


    // n_items() & is_empty()
    // Right-typed (signed integer) dynamic size of a collection.

    template< class Type >
    auto n_items( In_ref_<Type> o )
        -> Size
    { return o.size(); }

    template< size_t n >
    auto n_items( In_ref_<std::bitset<n>> o )
        -> Size
    { return o.count(); }       // Corresponds to std::set<int>::size()

    namespace impl {
        using std::declval;

        template< class Type >
        constexpr
        auto has_std_empty_checker( ... )
            -> bool
        { return false; }

        template< class Type >
        constexpr
        auto has_std_empty_checker( int )
            -> If_<
                Is_<bool, decltype( declval<const Type>().empty() )>,   // CFINAE
                Then_<bool>                                             // SFINAE
                >
        { return true; }

        struct Using_empty_method
        {
            template< class Type >
            auto is_empty( In_ref_<Type> o ) const
                -> bool
            { return o.empty(); }
        };

        struct Using_n_items_function
        {
            template< class Type >
            auto is_empty( In_ref_<Type> o ) const
                -> bool
            { return (n_items( o ) == 0); }
        };

    }  // namespace impl

    template< class Type >
    constexpr
    auto has_std_empty_checker()
        -> bool
    { return impl::has_std_empty_checker<Type>( 42 ); }

    template< class Type >
    auto is_empty( In_ref_<Type> o )
        -> bool
    {
        using Impl = Ifc_<
            has_std_empty_checker<Type>(),
            Then_<impl::Using_empty_method>,
            Else_<impl::Using_n_items_function>
            >;
        return Impl().is_empty( o );
    }

    template< size_t n >
    auto is_empty( In_ref_<std::bitset<n>> bits )
        -> bool
    { return bits.none(); }


    // length() & length_of_literal() & is_empty
    // Lengths of strings.

    template< class Char, size_t n >
    constexpr
    auto length_of_literal( In_ref_<Raw_array_of_<n, Char>> )   // "length" wraps this.
        -> Size
    { return n - 1; }

    template< class Type >
    auto length( Object_argument, In_ref_<Type> s )
        -> Size
    { return s.length(); }

    template< class Char
        , class Enabled_ = If_< Is_in_< Character_types, Char > >
        >
    auto length( Pointer_argument, In_value_<Ptr_<const Char>> s )
        -> Size
    {
        auto p = s;
        while( *p != 0 ) { ++p; }
        return p - s;
    }

    template< class Char, size_t n
        , class Enabled_ = If_< Is_in_< Character_types, Char > >
        >
    auto constexpr length( Array_argument, In_ref_<Raw_array_of_<n, Char>> a )
        -> Size
    { return length_of_literal( a ); }

    template< class Type >
    auto length( In_ref_<Type> o )
        -> Size
    { return length( Arg_kind_<Type>(), o ); }

    template< class Char
        , class Enabled_ = If_< Is_in_< Character_types, Char > >
        >
    auto is_empty( In_value_<Ptr_<const Char>> s )
        -> bool
    { return (*s == 0); }

}}  // namespace progrock::cppx
```

If you want to use this code, in part or in whole, directly without bringing in the supporting files from the [cppx library](https://github.com/alf-p-steinbach/cppx/blob/plutonium/core_language_support/sizes_and_lengths.hpp), you'll have to translate e.g. `In_` to the type you prefer for a logical in-argument, and so on. The cppx library is just a thing very much in-progress, but it's usable as-is already. It provides stuff such as the above, the very basics that somehow missed becoming part of the standard library, or even being proposed.