# Is the conversion from '(signed) -1' to 'unsigned long' standardized?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, specifications, unsigned, signed

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51234964/65863), you can find [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608111/why-is-18446744073709551615-1-true/51234964#comment89450401_51234964):

> Strictly speaking the bit representations of the two numbers before conversion being the same doesn't matter. Even with 1's complement or signed magnitude representations, **the conversion of (signed) -1 to unsigned long will always result in `ULONG_MAX`.** (The bit pattern will be the same after conversion of course).

I understand that you can represent `-1` in other ways than Two's Compliment, that's a valid addition that should be in my answer. But, in such implementations, is it safe to rely on the conversion to `ULONG_MAX`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is guaranteed regardless of the actual representation:

[[conv.integral]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.integral) (emphasis mine)

> A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another
>   integer type. A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type can be
>   converted to a prvalue of an integer type.
>
> **If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer** (modulo 2<sup>n</sup>
>   where `n` is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).
>   [ Note: In a two's complement representation, this conversion is
>   conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no
>   truncation).  — end note ]

Answer (score 4):

The commenter is correct; conversion to an unsigned integer type from any other integer type is always well-defined. If the range of the unsigned integer type is 0 to 2^N - 1, then the result of the conversion will be the original value reduced modulo 2^N. This will be the case even if (as in systems with a one's complement or sign-magnitude representation) said reduction modulo 2^N requires extra instructions.

Comment: And a standards link: http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral#2