# Is c++ still saving a "reference of the original value"?

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ and i have this code:

```
long long unsigned number;
cout << "Introduce a non negative number: \n";
cin >> number;
cout << "The number is equal to: " << number << endl;
cout << number*number;
```

When i introduce a negative value, per example -1 the message display that the number is equal to 18446744073709551615, and that is fine because i defined long long as a non negative number, so this number is something like an error.

What seems weird to me is that the square of the number gives the correct value, that is 1 in the case of -1 as input.

Despite the fact that the data entered by keyboard is not correct regarding the data type (unsigned), C ++ continues to giving the original input value(-1) as if it were stored somewhere.

So, where is C++ saving that value? How i can get it?

Similarly if i save the square as:

`int a = number*number`, per example in the case of input -1, `a = 1`

But when i do `cout << a/n;` its show 0 instead of 1/1 = 1 (Which I suppose is related to this)

Comment: This is because the binary representation of the numbers -1 and 18446744073709551615 is the same. The difference is whether you are treating it as a signed number or unsigned number. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608111/why-is-18446744073709551615-1-true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of modular arithmetic. When you assign `-1` to an unsigned number, it gets stored as a number of the form `2^n - 1` (`n` depends on the archtecture, but is the largest possible positive number of that type).

All operations on values of this type follow the same modular arithmetic. So when you multiply 2 `-1`s, you are actually doing:

```
=> (2^n - 1) x (2^n - 1) mod 2^n
=> 2^(2n) -2^(n+1) + 1 mod 2^n
=> 1 mod 2^n
```

Explaining the result of `1`.

Note that the program is *not* saving the value of `-1` anywhere, and the result you see is purely due to the modular arithmetic rules.

Comment: I'm kinda surprised the read even occurred. The formatted input was expecting an unsigned integer, and it obviously didn't get one when the OP inputted -1.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Hmm, seems that from c++17, cin is guaranteed to read `-1`, and assign the result given by passing it to `strtoull`.