# Is there a way to sort JSON entries, in mysql, based on a field?

Tags: mysql, json

I want to sort a **JSON** array, in mysql, based on my **date_requested** field, order would be ascending. Can I achieve that?

Array is like:

```
SET @nonSorted= '[
{
    "id": "119",
    "date_end": "2022-01-04 18:30:00",
    "occupied": "0",
    "date_begin": "2022-01-04 16:00:00",
    "idCategory": "2",
    "date_requested": "2022-01-01 11:14:39"
},
{
    "id": "134",
    "date_end": "2022-01-06 11:30:00",
    "occupied": "0",
    "date_begin": "2022-01-06 08:00:00",
    "idCategory": "4",
    "date_requested": "2022-01-02 16:15:49"
},
{
    "id": "142",
    "date_end": "2022-01-09 11:00:00",
    "occupied": "1",
    "date_begin": "2022-01-09 08:30:00",
    "idCategory": "4",
    "date_requested": "2022-01-01 18:11:20"
}
]';
```

Would love to get the array sorted by the field **date_requested**, I've also tried some solution I found on stackoverflow but it appears that doens't work in my case. The output should be like thtis:

```
'[{
    "id": "119",
    "date_end": "2022-01-04 18:30:00",
    "occupied": "0",
    "date_begin": "2022-01-04 16:00:00",
    "idCategory": "2",
    "date_requested": "2022-01-01 11:14:39"
},{
    "id": "142",
    "date_end": "2022-01-09 11:00:00",
    "occupied": "1",
    "date_begin": "2022-01-09 08:30:00",
    "idCategory": "4",
    "date_requested": "2022-01-01 18:11:20"
},{
    "id": "134",
    "date_end": "2022-01-06 11:30:00",
    "occupied": "0",
    "date_begin": "2022-01-06 08:00:00",
    "idCategory": "4",
    "date_requested": "2022-01-02 16:15:49"
}
]'
```

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: Why do you use JSON? You have an array where each element is an object with an identical set of fields. This should be another normal table, with six columns. Then all the troubles with JSON vanish. You can search and sort efficiently, and it's easy to write the query to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution for MySQL 8:

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(object)
FROM (
    SELECT object
    FROM JSON_TABLE(@nonSorted,
                    '$[*]' COLUMNS (object JSON PATH '$',
                                    date_requested DATETIME PATH '$.date_requested')) jsontable
    ORDER BY date_requested LIMIT 18446744073709551615
) parsed;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4d7a5ffa690becda0fad27cc9d0a326

Comment: seeing this question on SO ([Why is (18446744073709551615 == -1) true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608111/why-is-18446744073709551615-1-true)), I wonder why there is a LIMIT on above query ... (/me is just curious)

Comment: @Luuk LIMIT is used for to forbid ORDER BY ignoring. The parameter of LIMIT clause is BIGINT UNSIGNED, and used value is maxvalue for this datatype.

Comment: Ah, a trick/feature to solve this problem " JSON_ARRAYAGG cannot currently be used as a window function."

Comment: @Luuk Yes, JSON_ARRAYAGG does not implement ORDER BY clause (like in GROUP_CONCAT).

Answer (score 1):

This will return the 3 parts in correct order, you will only have to merge them back to 1 JSON:

```
select 
   JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, CONCAT("$[",t2.i,"]")) B
from t1 
cross join (select 0 as i union select 1 union select 2) t2
order by JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, CONCAT("$[",t2.i,"].date_requested")) ASC;
```

output:

| B |
| --- |
| {"id": "119", "date_end": "2022-01-04 18:30:00", "occupied": "0", "date_begin": "2022-01-04 16:00:00", "idCategory": "2", "date_requested": "2022-01-01 11:14:39"} |
| {"id": "142", "date_end": "2022-01-09 11:00:00", "occupied": "1", "date_begin": "2022-01-09 08:30:00", "idCategory": "4", "date_requested": "2022-01-01 18:11:20"} |
| {"id": "134", "date_end": "2022-01-06 11:30:00", "occupied": "0", "date_begin": "2022-01-06 08:00:00", "idCategory": "4", "date_requested": "2022-01-02 16:15:49"} |