# Loop ignores limits: How can I handle this corrupt c++ program?

Tags: c++, corruption

When I execute my program it doesn't terminate. I haven't changed anything and it has been working before. There is clearly something wrong but I don't understand what and why.

In the screenshot you can see the line

```
for ( size_t n = 0; n <= (size_t)maxState; n++ ) nodes.push_back(nullptr);
```

You can also see that `maxState` is -1, so `(size_t)maxState` should be 0. On the right side of the image you can see the values for n and the size of the `nodes` vector.

[image: n goes to infitiny]

I've taken the screenshot after pausing execution. When I resume it doesn't terminate. I've read some things about heap corruption, but without working solutions. Also I'm not sure if heap corruption is the real cause for this strange effect.

I already tried to clean and rebuild.

Comment: *You can also see that `maxState` is -1, so `(size_t)maxState` should be 0.* Not at all, you might want to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711522/what-happens-if-i-assign-a-negative-value-to-an-unsigned-variable).

Comment: where did you get the idea `(size_t)(-1) == 0`?

Comment: I checked it before by doing `auto n = (size_t)maxState`. Also, I already mentioned that I haven't changed anything in the code. It has been working before. So it's totally wrong to mark this as duplicate. Maybe duplicate, but not to *that* question.

Comment: Reopened; the duplicated addresses the **cause** of the problem, but doesn't address the appropriate **solution** here.

Comment: @Sadik "_I checked it before by doing `auto n = (size_t)maxState`_", and yet, when I did the same in [this code snippet](https://ideone.com/cJIBWU), the cast doesn't make it equal to 0. So, it's still unclear where you got that assumption from.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius thank you. So I don't understand why it always had been 0 in thousands of tries before. The code is from a github repository btw. Nobody raised complains there about this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mess with `size_t` here. You haven't mentioned the actual type of `maxState`, but if its value is -1, then it's a **signed** type. So use a **signed** index variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxState; ++i)
```

This will execute zero times when the value of `maxState` is negative.