# Why does the follwoing program work

Tags: c, debugging

```
#include <stdio.h>

void circle(int *,int *,int *);

int main() {
    int x,y,z;
    printf("please enter 3 numbers = ");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&x,&y,&z);

    circle(&x,&y,&z);

    printf("x=%d  y=%d  z=%d",x,y,z);


}

void circle(int *a,int *b ,int *c) {
    int *d;
    d=*a;
    *a=*b;

    *b=*c;
    *c=d;
}
```

The above code is for circularly exchanging the values of `x, y, z` using functions.
In the above code I have used `*d` or `d` is an `unsigned` integer, still if in

```
d=*a
```

if `x` (or `a`) = `-1` then also the code works.

Comment: Don't ignore the warnings your compiler gives you - it means your code is wrong. If you're not getting warnings (cos you really should with the above code), turn them on

Comment: btw, good naming of functions doesn't hurt. I would've expected this to be a drawing function...

Comment: `d=*a;` is assigning integer to pointer. `*c=d;` is assigning pointer to integer. Perfect recipe for troubles.

Answer (score 1):

```
void circle(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
  int *d;
  d = *a;
  ...
```

Here `d = *a;` puts an `int` into a pointer.

Decent compilers should issue a warning such as:

`'=': 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'`

As the size of `int` is usually smaller or equal than the size of a pointer, your code still works, but it is undefined behaviour, it may not work on another platform. Undefined behaviour includes "apparetly working fine".

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering why your program still works when you assign a negative value to an unsigned integer, you should know what happens when you assign a negative value to an unsigned integer on this link:

[What happens if I assign a negative value to an unsigned variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711522/what-happens-if-i-assign-a-negative-value-to-an-unsigned-variable)