# difference between i + 1 < vec.size() and i < vec.size() - 1

Tags: c++, runtime-error, size

while programming I found out that my code was giving runtime error when I was using condition `i < vec.size() - 1` but was working fine for `i + 1< vec.size()`.
here `vec` was an empty `std::vector`.

```
//giving error
vector<int> vec;
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size() - 1; i++)
{
    //some code
}
//not giving error
vector<int> vec;
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < vec.size(); i++)
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: Your code iterates only over `size()` - 1 elements (meaning it misses the last element of the vector. ) Is this what you actually want, or did you actually intend to iterate over the whole vector?

Answer (score 13):

The method `std::vector::size` returns a `std::size_t` which is unsigned. So if it is empty, you will get `0 - 1`, but represented as an unsigned number, that will underflow and become `18446744073709551615` according to [two's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711522/what-happens-if-i-assign-a-negative-value-to-an-unsigned-variable).

Comment: note that it's not literally `0 - 1` but either `0u - 1`, `0ul - 1` or `0ull - 1` (implementation-dependant).

Comment: @StackDanny This site needs a way to mark expressions as pure math to disambiguate from programming language expresions :)

Comment: Note that whatever "two's complement" says doesn't affect what the result of `std::size_t(0) - 1`, because unsigned types don't have a sign representation. Standard specifies that the result is congruent modulo the maximum representable value + 1 (or 2**bits). -1 is congruent with X - 1 modulo X.

Comment: Indeed, two's complement has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @eerorika that could be a nice feature-request on meta stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

Sidenote. It's not a good idea to compare signed and unsigned numbers. In C++20 we will have a new function `std::ssize` that returns a signed type. Then your example written as

```
 for (std::ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < std::ssize(vec) - 1; ++i)
 {
     //some code
 }
```

will be perfectly valid.

Note also how `i` is declared to be an [`std::ptrdiff_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t) (a signed integer type) to indicate array indexing.