# Why does GCC only complain about an unsigned int argument being used with %i when -pedantic is given?

Tags: c, gcc

[`sscanf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) says (emphasis mine):

> **`i`**
>   Matches an optionally signed integer; **the next pointer must be a pointer to `int`**.  The integer is read in base 16 if it begins with `0x` or `0X`, in base 8 if it begins with `0`, and in base 10 otherwise.  Only characters that correspond to the base are used.

However GCC does not complain about using an `unsigned int` with `%i` unless `-pedantic` is given. This is different from the behavior I'm used to, where GCC will warn for any mismatched type and format string.

Why does this combination behave differently?

Given that this warning is  not included in the common `-Wall`  set of warnings, is it acceptable to pass `unsigned int` to `%i`?

---

Example program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    unsigned int u;
    float f;

    scanf("%i", &i);
    scanf("%i", &u);
    scanf("%i", &f);

    return 0;
}
```

Without `-pedantic`, GCC complains about `%i` and `float *`, but not `unsigned int *`:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra scanf_i.c 
scanf_i.c: In function ‘main’:
scanf_i.c:11:13: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%i", &f);
            ~^   ~~
            %e
```

With `-pedantic`, GCC complains about both:
Output *with* `-pedantic`:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic scanf_i.c 
scanf_i.c: In function ‘main’:
scanf_i.c:10:13: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned int *’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%i", &u);
            ~^   ~~
            %i
scanf_i.c:11:13: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%i", &f);
            ~^   ~~
            %e
```

GCC version:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
```

Comment: I almost always use `-Wpedantic` to avoid unexpected compiler extensions anyway. "_...is it acceptable to pass `unsigned int` to `%i`_?" -- rather than look at manpages, go straight to the source: ["_The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to signed integer._"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12) Passing `unsigned int` to `%i` leads to undefined behavior and should be avoided.

Comment: I was also trying to figure out if this was actually UB. Would it be more correct to `sscanf` into an `int` and then [assign that to an `unsigned int`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2711522/119527)?

Comment: Sure, that would be fine. In some circumstances it might also be convenient to take input as a string and use [`strtoul` with a base argument of 0](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.4p5).

Comment: See C11 draft standard n1570, *6.2.5 Types 9 The range of nonnegative values of a signed integer type is a subrange of the
corresponding unsigned integer type, and the representation of the same value in each
type is the same. 41)*, where footnote: *41) The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as
arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions.* while the footnote is non-normative, the consequence of the normative rule is that the warning is only sound for numbers that are not representable in either type.

Comment: I should have asked the question "can I pass an `unsigned int` for `%i`?"

Comment: @EOF -- "_the warning is only sound for numbers that are not representable in either type_": a compiler diagnostic is only required for constraint violations. There is no constraint violation in passing `unsigned int` to `%i`, but it is still UB as: ["_If a ''shall'' or ''shall not'' requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime- constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined._"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p2)

Comment: @exnihilo I'm not talking about constraint violations, neither compiletime nor runtime. I'm talking about the fact that passing a `unsigned *` where an `int *` is expected is explicitly **not undefined in some cases**, namely when the value referenced by the pointer, written as one of the types and read as the other, is representable in both. As the part of the standard I quoted describes.

Comment: @EOF -- it is explicitly undefined in the case of OP question.

Comment: @exnihilo Iff the input corresponding to the `"%i"` is not representable by both `int` and `unsigned` (which is user-controlled, and thus *should* always be checked). Otherwise, no UB here, and gcc may not want to warn for this by default because false positive warnings decrease trust in tools.

Comment: @EOF -- "_Otherwise, no UB here_" -- that is incorrect. The Standard says explicitly, as I have already quoted: ["_The corresponding argument **shall** be a pointer to signed integer_"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12) for `%i`, and ["_If a **''shall''** or ''shall not'' requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime- constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined._"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p2)

Comment: @EOF -- You can't be much more explicit than this. Representability is not the issue here.

Comment: @exnihilo Well, I suppose this depends on whether the specific requirements of the I/O library do (or even *can*) override the fundamental rules of the language, as per *6.5 Expressions 7 An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
the following types: 88)
— a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
— a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object, [...]* and the section I previously quoted, which *explicitly* describes this as **interchangeable**.

Answer (score 2):

`-Wformat-signedness` controls whether warnings are raised when the argument type differs only in signedness from what's expected.

From the [gcc(1) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html):

> **`-Wformat-signedness`**
>   If -Wformat is specified, also warn if the format string requires an unsigned argument and the argument is signed and vice versa.

The man page does not explicitly state that this flag is included in `-pedantic`, (`-Wpedantic`) but it does say:

> However, if `-Wpedantic` is used with `-Wformat`, warnings are given about format features not in the selected standard version.

Comment: Both the question and answer provide good information about the overly misused `%i` format specifier.

Comment: @David Why do you feel it is overly misused? In my case, I'd like to scan either a decimal or hex `unsigned int`. But no standard library function can easily do this.

Comment: Because with a number (a large number) of new user questions it is used as a magical integer specifier for all types regardless of the signedness of the variable to be filled. Especially where the user is using it to read hex formatted input.