# Loop breaks after exception is catched

Tags: c++, vector, try-catch

The for loop breaks after i=-1, And sum is 0.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> vec{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int sum = 0;
    
    for (int i = -1; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        try {
            throw vec.at(i);
        } catch (int x) {
            sum += x;
        } catch (...) {
            cout << "Exception Handled" << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The sum should be 10. And accesing index -1 should be catched.

Comment: Do you know what `throw` does? Do you know what `std::vector::at()` does?

Comment: Your loop never runs since `-1` is converted to an unsigned integer and that converted integer is larger than `size()`

Comment: On a side note: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/)

Comment: Yes, accessing -1 should throw an exception that gets caught. But it doesn't, so that exception can't have been thrown. Since it was never thrown, you can't have executed the first iteration. Since you never executed the first iteration, there must be something fishy about the loop condition. And a modern compiler should warn you about the different signedness of the comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vec.size()` returns an **unsigned** integer type (usually `std::size_t`).

You are comparing a *signed* integer `i` to an *unsigned* integer `size()`, so the compiler will convert the value of `i` to an unsigned type when comparing it to the value of `size()`. And `-1` converts to a VERY LARGE unsigned value (see: [What happens if I assign a negative value to an unsigned variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711522/)), which in this case is the maximum value that `size_t` can hold.

Since that converted value is larger than the actual `size()` value, the expression `i < vec.size()` evaluates as `false` on the 1st iteration, causing your loop to exit immediately without ever entering its body at all.